# How to create a smiliar Simpler Viewer image gallery thumbnail effect using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, effect

How do you create an effect like the Thumbnail in Simple Viewer image gallery using JQuery? The effect is When the user moves the mouse over an image, four sides of the image get covered by white color and when the user moves the mouse away from the image, the original image returns. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

You may also like this one

http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/